# Check the example below. Trying to make a sql query which will work in Derby database

Tags: sql, group-by, derby

I have two tables.

**Table 1**

```
Name Month Hours
A    5     2
B    20    1
C    30    5
B    4     6
A    6     3
```

**Table 2**

```
Name    Hours2
A       5
B       6
A       8
```

**Result Table**

```
Name    Hours   Hours2  month
A       2       13      5
A       3       13      6
B       1       6       20
B       6       6       4
```

So what's happening here is, there is a join between both tables where condition is that the **Name** matches. And on individual table there **should** be group by to remove multiple entries but if I do that then need to use aggregate function there.

Using aggregate function on Hours and Hours2 will yield most of it but if I want to see month field values as unique values against it then it is not possible by group by and trying to do **partition by** did not work as derby does not support it.

I am not able to make a query that can do the above.

Comment: From table 2, you need to sum up hours for A and get the result set (remove its duplicates as well). Then, you can join that result with table 1 to select only name=A.

Comment: what is your expected out

Comment: Why no B row in the result?

Comment: @jarlh its just an example, there can be **B** in the output.

Comment: Also @Gimhani, thanks for the answer but I do not want to use where condition i.e. I don't want results just for **A** but for all the values in the matching columns. I have written about it in the description as well.

Comment: Do you mean the given expected result doesn't match the sample data?

Comment: @jarlh Yes, I am sorry. As I was not sure what the exact output would be thus kept it like that. I have edited the question so that future viewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think below will work for you

```
select t1.Name,t1.Hours,t2.Hours2,t1.month from  Table1 t1 
inner join                                           
( SELECT  
  Name,SUM(Hours2)  as Hours2
  from Table2 group by Name     
 ) t2 on t1.Name=t2.Name
```